# Как отличить системный файл от пользовательского в Linux?

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Не могу понять,как отличить системный файл от пользовательского в Linux.Как понять,что файл, находящийся в системной директории создан или принадлежит системе,а не пользователю?

Comment: Можете проверить постановку вопроса? __очистить системный файл от пользовательского__ (чего пользовательского?). Может вы имели в виду корневую директорию (root directory "/")? Такая постановка вопроса не имеет смысла. В Unix подобных системах "Системе" принадлежат все файлы, но может быть создано н-е количество пользователей от UUID 1 до N  (UUID 0 - root пользователь, админ, главный "пользователь" системы который имеет право редактировать-читать-исправлять __любые__  фалы-директории)

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос абсолютно неясен ввиду надуманности определений: «системный файл» и «пользовательский файл». когда автор вопроса уточнит (в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]), что **он** подразумевает под этими терминами, вопрос стоит открыть (и ответить на него).

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае - никак. Но можно попробовать посмотреть на то, кому пренадлежит (это уже тавтология) файл - `ls -al имя-файла`. Системные файлы обычно пренадлежат руту. Пользовательские файлы принадлежат пользователю. Но если рут - тоже пользователь, тогда это не подходит.

Также можно спросить у пакетного менеджера о файле. В случае убунту/дебиана это `apt-file find <имя файла>`. В случае gentoo - `equery belong <имя файла>`.

В общем случае задача очень похожа на классическую задачу по поиску руткитов. И решается она соответствующим образом - на свежеустановленной системе делается снимок файловой системы с hash-сумами. А потом аккуратно сравнивается.

Да, и не стоит забывать о дате модификации. Хотя при постоянных обновлениях оно уже и не так эффективно.

Comment: Можете объяснить роль **apt** в выяснении вопроса о "принадлежности файлов пользователям". Такой пример: был установлен vsftpd от UUID=0 создали пользователей в /etc/vsftpd.d/ - кому в этом случае принадлежат файлы; системе или пользователям? И как это выяснить при помощи пакетного менеджера.

Comment: apt знает, какие файлы он ставил. Также, обычно, в пакетах есть информация о том, какие файлы этот пакет может создать, что бы потом при удалении пакета подчистить.

Но как  я сказал в самом ответе, иногда вопрос, кому принадлежит файл очень и очень неоднозначен. Поэтому, я обычно считаю, что файлов, которые принадлежат системе нет. Есть рутовые файлы и пользовательские. В нормальных системах рут не создает просто так обычные файлы, обычно он создает "системные файлы".

Comment: @KoVadim, так что же это такое: «пользовательские и системные» файлы? просветите нас, тёмных, пожалуйста.

Comment: ещё раз пишу для тролей. По факту, пользовательские файлы находятся в домашних каталогах пользователей и принадлежат им. "Системные файлы" (да, я в кавычках специально пишу) принадлежат руту (пользователь root).  Но это все очень и очень относительно. Очень

Comment: ИМХО этот вопрос стоило задать OP'у прежде  чем отвечать... или хотя бы сразу уточнить, что строго говоря такого понятия как «системный файл» в *nix ОС **нет**...

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я выбрал путь со сравниванием хэшей. Почитав комментарии,я понял,что по сути , в Линукс нет отличия системного файла от пользовательского,но поясню,что я подразумевал,когда задавал вопрос: под системным файлом я имел ввиду те файлы,которые устанавливаются при установке оси,то есть те файлы,которые отвечают за нормальное функционирование и работу системы. Под пользовательскими файлами ,я подразумевал те файлы,которые загрузил сам юзер через pip или gitclone и тд. или просто скачал из интернета или какого-либо стороннего носителя.

Answer (score 2):

> Как понять,что файл принадлежит системе,а не пользователю?

Вопрос, с точки зрения люниха, абсолютно несуразный. Любой (я подчёркиваю - любой!) файл в ФС принадлежит одному и только одному ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЮ. Кому именно принадлежат файлы в некоторой директории легко узнать с помощью команды *ls -l*. Другое дело, что пользователи бывают разные. С разными правами. И есть один - суперпользователь с абсолютными правами - *root*. Но не все "системные" файлы принадлежат ему. Например, очень важный "системный" файл *syslog* принадлежит пользователю *syslog* из группы *adm*.

Но владельцем любого файла в любом месте может быть (в принципе) любой пользователь. Понятий

- Системный файл
- Пользовательский файл

В люнихе просто не существует. Автор вопроса, по всей вероятности, пытается виндовозную идеологию применить к ФС люниха. Они - разные! Сильно разные...

Можно привести некую аналогию в файловой структуре директорий, рекомендуемой в люнихе:

- /bin - Программы, обеспечивающие функционирование самой системы - например - bash
- /usr/bin - Программы, обеспечивающие работу пользователя на всех компах. Например - почта, браузеры, компилляторы
- /usr/local/bin - Программы, которые нужны пользователю только на этом компе
- ~/bin - Программы, используемые только данным пользователем.

Здесь есть некая анадлогия с виндовозными папками ProgramFiles и System32/ Впрочем - достаточно далёкая аналогия.

Никакой пользователь (кроме *root*) не сможет записать файл в папку, принадлежащую не ему, если хозяин не предоставил ему соответствующих прав. Дело не в том, кто **владелец** файла, а в том, какие **права** он дал посторонним.

Comment: `s/люниха/линукса/gi`

Comment: Знаете, в те доисторические времена, когда на просторах СССР гуляла только одна ОС, а именно - ОС ЕС, в СССР был завезён невиданный зверь под названием UNIX. А поскольку в те времена программисты вовсе не обязательно знали английский язык, то тут же появилась ироническая поговорка: " У нас - ОС ЕС, а операционная система - у них". :-) Кстати, под горячую руку можно и Техас переименовать в Тексас! :-)